# Two Spinners and extracting strings from each. Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My app offers guitar players a page they can define a song in terms of Name, chords used, and relevant scales.

My app has two spinners that have parts of a fully formed guitar chord, and another spinner for 'split' chords, so three spinners in all.  They are working nicely.

In the Activity, one spinner holds a list of guitar chord primitives (i.e. 'C#'), and the second spinner holds a list of chord modifiers (i.e. 'maj7').

Then, from each of the spinners, I need to have the two strings combined into a textView or list which will hold something like "Gm, A#, C#maj7..." which are the user's chosen chords for performing the song, and they need to be saved for later use in a performance page.

I need to be able to store the combined strings from spinner1 and spinner2 to get 'C#maj7'.  This algorithm is necessary since the list of chords would number in about 40,000 list items if you did it in just one spinner, so the 2-spinner method makes sense, I believe.

What I want know is:

1. How to get the strings out of the spinners and into a textView or whatever 'box' you might suggest.
2. How to combine the strings, which I can probably figure out on my own...

I've looked over hundreds of articles here in stackoverflow, and most of them are outdated or irrelevant, and often don't work with current code.  Some are several years old, and usually codes are not quite the same it seems.

Here is my activity_new_song.xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    tools:context="com.edsets.gigmaster.NewSong">

    <!-- This is the title "Song Name" -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/new_song_name"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- The user types in the song name -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:width="400dp"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <!-- This is the grid which holds the layout elements -->

    <!-- This is the Title "Your Chords" -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Your Chords:"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Primary"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Modifiers"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Split Chords"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:entries="@array/PrimaryChords"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:entries="@array/Modifiers"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7"
        android:entries="@array/SplitChords"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my class "NewSong.java"

```
package com.edsets.gigmaster;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class NewSong extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_song);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.PrimaryChords, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_song, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: In Layout have three Spinner but in code using one?

Comment: When want to get values from Spinner?

Comment: I am only working on one at a time for the moment.  I will add the other spinners once I have a clue how to extract the strings from the spinners.

Answer (score 0):

Fast answers, hopefully enough:

> 1. How to get the strings out of the spinners and into a textView or whatever 'box' you might suggest.

You can get the selected item by:

```
Object selectedItem = youtSpinner.getSelectedItem();
```

And cast it to whatever class they are. For instance, if your items are Strings, this should be fine to get the items:

```
String selectedItem = (String) yourSpinner.getSelectedItem();
```

> 2. How to combine the strings, which I can probably figure out on my own...

Just cat them:

String result = string1 + string2;

---

EDIT:

Try with spinner adapter:

```
yourSpinner.getAdapter().getItem(position)
```

Comment: String selectedItem = (String) spinner1.getSelectedItem(); does not allow 'selectedItem', it is grayed out, and says it will never be used.

Comment: I've been trying this for a week or more.  Must be something with API level, or???

Comment: Can you invoke `int index = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();`?

Comment: Interesting, it's not there!

Comment: int index = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();  'index' is grayed out.

Comment: But you can invoke `getSelectedItemPosition`?